# How to convert a string to datetime in ruby

Tags: ruby, datetime

In ruby with a string like "Tuesday, January 19, 2016 8:00 pm" what options do I have for converting this into a date/time format recognized by ruby?

edit: Similar questions ask about converting from mm/dd/yyyy format, my question is about a different format but it appears that the answer is the same. I understand why this may appear to be a duplicate it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime.strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-_strptime).

Example:

```
2.1.2-perf :029 > DateTime.strptime("Tuesday, January 19, 2016 8:00 pm", "%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M %p")
 => #<DateTime: 2016-01-19T20:00:00+00:00 ((2457407j,72000s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```